# css focus color overrides background color

Tags: css, focus

I want to "highlight" an element when it's focused.
In this example below if you click on text it also changes background color.

I can't change (add/remove) elements, I can add css class to elements classes only.

Also I don't know what kind of background was applied before (color, gradient, image) and so on.

this is unfocused element
[image]

this is result focused state
[image]

I'd like add highlight white color with opacity and preserve background color/image/gradient.

expected result:
[image]

```css
b {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.app-focus:focus {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<b id="id1" class="app-focus" tabIndex="1">text</b>
```

Comment: just remove the `background-color: white;` and set opacity a little more higher like `0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two methods to do it

1 - Only use opacity in the `:focus` code.

```
.app-focus:focus {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

2 - Use `::before` to make the overlay effect.

```css
b {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 42px;
  position: relative;
}

b::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.app-focus:focus::before {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<b id="id1" class="app-focus" tabIndex="1">text</b>
```